# One of the media keys( next track ) is stuck and is making the keyboard useless. I want to disable it but I'm not getting the keycode using xev

Tags: keyboard, xmodmap, xev

The next track key is stuck and the screen is continously showing not allowed sign. None of the other keys work when this key gets pressed automatically I want to disable this particular key but I'm not able to find it's keycode using xev, i also tried using xmodmap -pke but couldn't find the key as the names were too confusing. How do I permanently disable this key?

Comment: If you can not use the keyboard how are you trying different commands?

Comment: I can type commands by clicking and holding a numpad key and backspace together.I have to type every command like this, other times( when I'm not trying to solve this problem) I usually disable the laptop keyboard using xinput float and use an external keyboard